# Why is my ag-grid filter removed when an item is removed from grid array?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a standard ag-grid in an Angular project. When users click a button on then home page, it'll direct them to the grid and apply a filter to the grid. A user can then select one or more rows and press a button that does stuff in the back end, and then removes the item from the array.

**Here it removes the item from the array:**

```
this.taskService.complete(task).subscribe(response => {                   
        this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(x => x.TaskId !== response.TaskID);
    }
```

This all should work fine. However, after my method has run it hits core.mjs (which is from angular) and removes my filter. You can see the method in the code below. It removes the filter on the onLeave(zone) method

**This is from core.mjs. THIS IS NOT MY CODE AND CANNOT BE CHANGED**

```
function forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior(zone) {
    const delayChangeDetectionForEventsDelegate = () => {
        delayChangeDetectionForEvents(zone);
    };
    zone._inner = zone._inner.fork({
        name: 'angular',
        properties: { 'isAngularZone': true },
        onInvokeTask: (delegate, current, target, task, applyThis, applyArgs) => {
            try {
                onEnter(zone);
                return delegate.invokeTask(target, task, applyThis, applyArgs);
            }
            finally {
                if ((zone.shouldCoalesceEventChangeDetection && task.type === 'eventTask') ||
                    zone.shouldCoalesceRunChangeDetection) {
                    delayChangeDetectionForEventsDelegate();
                }
                onLeave(zone);
            }
        },
```

This is being called automatically after all of my code has run, so even when I add my setFilter() method after "this.tasks = ...." it will still not remain filtered.

How do I stop Angular/core.mjs from running this?

Comment: For what? I'm removing 1 item from the grid array, and then want to apply a filter.

Comment: what the console.log(this.tasks) inside the subscribe says?

Comment: it has the object (row) that was selected. It does everything it's supposed to do, it just removes the filter after all of my code has run